# Xpage Time zone return GMT format when set "Time zone" property as browser

Tags: xpages

I am working on create calendar view to show calendar entries from calendar database in browser/mobile using fullcalendar JQuery plug in.

(http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/)
(http://keithstric.homeip.net/A55BAC/demo/fullCalendar.nsf)

The calendar view can be accessible by different region(different time zone).

User want to see calendar entries in their local time zone instead of server time zone.

So, xpage has feature to use browser time zone. Account to user time zone.

(http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/XPagesTimeZones.htm)

If enable Time zone as browser(user time zone), able to get browser time zone in server side using context.getTimeZone().

Programmatic ally, convert Date object stored in calendar entry to local time zone and send to fullcallendar plug in. Its works for me.

I like to display indication to user, what time zone they are.(e.g. CET, GMT, EST, IST)

My desired outcome:

**your time zone is IST**

My current outcome
**Your time  zone is GMT +5.30**

My code like this:
**"your time zone is "context.getTimeZone().getDisplayName()**

how can i get time zone label instead of GMT format? else do we have any way to convert GMT to time zone label?

Comment: Take one step back and elaborate: what is your desired outcome (not: how you try to get there)? And why would you want to set Timezone to browser?